# Export a function in NodeJS module

Tags: node.js, express

I have a module in NodeJS which has the following definition:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function myFunction(){
    //do some stuff
};

router.get('/url', function(req, res, callback) {   
    var data = myFunction();
    res.render('index', {
        item: data
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want it to be called in both ways:

HTTP petition:

```
http://localhost:3090/url
```

As a function in another module:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
var data = myModule.myFunction();
```

I can access the module by HTTP in the way shown above. However, I don't know how to export `myFunction` to be used in another module. I have tried the following without any success:

```
router.myFunction = myFunction;
module.exports = router;
```

And:

```
module.exports = router;
module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

How could I solve this problemn?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: how about `module.exports.router = router;
module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;` ? sounds more like you'd want to split the two in two seperate modules though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make these changes

use exports to expose multiple functions

```
exports.router = router; 
exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

for including them both in other file(path to myModule can vary as per your structure) you can now include them as

```
var routes= require('./myModule').router;
var myfunction = require('./myModule').myFunction;
```

Comment: `function myFunction()` will work just fine.  Explicit assignment isn't necessary.

Comment: My pleasure, great to hear it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to also sum up everything you're exporting at the end of the module - basically construct the exports object:

```
module.exports = {

    myFunction: myFunction,
    router: router,
    someConstant: 42,
    anotherValue: calculateThisValue()
}
```

At any time, `module.exports` is a global per-file object you get when you require that file. If you put nothing there, it'll be `undefined`. If you make it a function, then it'll be a function. If you make an object literal like above, you get an object. You can also export primitives, like dates, arrays, or whatever else you may think of.